# As moving to next route in react route, the next route cursor position is same or some how similar to the previous route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have been messing around with react-router for sometime now. I am getting this problem while navigating into new route. I have following route

```
 <Router history={ history } >
        <Route component={ Context } dataStore={ dataStore } >
            <Route path="/" component={ MainApp }></Route>
            <Route path="/search" component={ SearchPage }></Route>
            <Route path="/:pageUrl" component={ LandingPage }></Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
```

Everything works perfectly. But...
I do have a link in **bottom** of the search page which will navigate back to '/' i.e home page.

```
<Link to="/"><img src="/static/images/el/app-logo.png" alt="" /></Link>
```

Now the problem is, it does navigate to the home page but, the pages cursor position is same as in the previous page. I need to fix this and make it as if actual redirect happened and page should be scrolled to top.(returning back from any other state makes sense but even for the first redirection the change in page position seems ugly).Struggling on this for a while now... I could use `<a href="/">` but this seems to actually redirect and refresh the page. I want to persist the behavior react-route as in SPA. Is there any help out there?? 
Thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scroll-behavior](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-behavior) or [use-scroll-behavior](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-scroll-behavior).